# perimeter wiring LED lights thru pipe fence

Tags: wiring

I have a some used airport taxiway lights, and want to place some around perimeter of 4 acre property on top of existing pipe fence for looks. Want to install about 16 lights total. Will rewire with LED at 7-9 watt range. Can run wiring thru the top rail of the fence. The distance is the problem...can do in two circuits of about 1000ft each, with 8 lights each. So to the experts, I will take any advice i can get. Specifically: will 12/2 wire suffice? Since LEDs come in 110 or 220 should I wire circuit at one or the other and why please? Can I use one good quality timer for both circuits starting at source and dividing there? The idea is low cost lighting of property for aesthetics, so if this will spin my meter like a top may have to rethink...and do not want to spend a ton. I already have a 2000' of 12/2 wire, a heavy duty mechanical timer, power at the meter located where I can divide into two "runs", enough taxi way lights to light an entire airport, and the property already has pipe fence to run wire thru. LED rework of lights is cheap. Soooo...besides the fact that I am nuts, advise please>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 1):

Depending entirely on what the LED you insert is, the BEST way to do long runs of LEDs is to put them in series and run the required DC current through the system at whatever voltage that requires (the LED supply will be controlling the current closely in that case, the voltage will be what's needed to run the current.) But that requires that you use LEDs that are "bare" in the sense of having no attached/built in power supply.

If you are using 120/240VAC LEDS (which are low-voltage DC LEDs attached to a power supply which uses 120/240VAC and does the conversion locally) then you will perforce be wiring in parallel at 120/240V.

16 9 watt LEDS, assume pessimistically that they are quoting LED power use and ignoring losses in the power supply, say 80% to be pessimistic about power supply efficiency, comes to about 180 watts, should run 5.5 hours on a kilo-Watt-hour (for your pricing) and draw 0.75A on 240V or 1.5A on 120V. At 12 hours per night (average across the year) and 15 cents a kilowatt hour, about $120/year.

Assuming that your wire is rated for use in conduit/wet locations, likely won't be a problem, though it will obviously be better on 240V (less current for the same power, so less voltage drop.) If you have 12/2 UF wire that will be true, if you have 12/2 NM wire it is absolutely not true, and a code violation. I'm not going to bother sorting out the actual voltage drop from distributed lights (which will be less), but treated as a lump load at the end of the wire, 0.75A at 240V on 1000 feet of 12Ga results in 3% drop, so you would be fine. If dividing into two 8 light circuits, you'll be fine on either voltage.

How much you'll annoy your neighbors (especially if any of them like to look at the stars) is a whole other question.

Comment: THANKS!!!  need to ponder the DC setup idea...that is interesting....

Comment: Follow up to your answer....why is 12/2 nm in conduit a code violation? Fire issue or power drain? Does this mean running my 12/2 nm thru 2 3/8 in pipe (top rail) an issue? (in rural non-code area)

Comment: NM is NOT waterproof - it is strictly an interior type wire. ALL exterior conduit is both defined as, and in practice usually is, a wet location. Therefore, all wiring in exterior conduit must be a wet-rated wire / insulation type.

Comment: makes sense...was not sure since wire is 48 in above ground and pipe sealed....ugg....otherwise it would seem that wiring at 120 or 240 i will have no issues due to light load...if I read you correctly...and since i am a commercial pilot and retired Air traffic controller i like airplanes....Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a licensed electrician, nor do I play one on TV, I only took a couple classes in electrical wiring at my local community college.

Having said that, and ignoring code issues I'm not qualified to speak to, the rule of thumb I was given is that for every 100 feet of wire run, you should increase the size by 1 to account for voltage drop. So, if your normal load will be under 15 A, at which point a 14/2 romex cable would be indicated, you're looking at going 10 sizes larger - to 3/0 or 4/0 (I'm a little fuzzy on sizes bigger than 6 gauge). Any smaller and you run the risk of not having enough voltage at the end of the run to power the LED, and of running into code issues with voltage drop.

Bottom line - I don't think it's going to be worth the money you have to spend to do this.

Comment: As a matter of personal policy I usually avoid downvoting on questions I've also answered, and I'll stick to that here. But your thumbs are all wrong when you apply them blindly. If there WAS a 15 amp load at the end of 1000 feet of wire (there isn't) 1/0 copper would be adequate, but 3/0 aluminum would cost a lot less. Given an actual load of 1.5 or 0.75A, this is absurd (admittedly, the question is also somewhat absurd if there are no airplanes running around the perimeter of the property.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that rule of thumb has limitations, and I'm not entirely sure it's that accurate to begin with.

Comment: Is the current draw related to the power being pulled at the end? In my case one AMP total on the line.